# how to download image in Goutte

Tags: php, web-crawler, guzzle, goutte

I want to download an image in this [page](http://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=medium&illust_id=48258889). The image source is`http://i2.pixiv.net/c/600x600/img-master/img/2015/01/19/12/17/13/48258889_p0_master1200.jpg`. I try to download it use this:

```
$client = new Goutte\Client ();
$client->getClient->get($img_url, array('save_to' => $img_url_save_name));
```

But I failed, then I realize if I directly access`http://i2.pixiv.net/c/600x600/img-master/img/2015/01/19/12/17/13/48258889_p0_master1200.jpg`, I are denied by CDN nginx server. I have to access this image link in 'www.pixv.net' page, which means my image request reference is 'www.pixv.net'. How to do this in Goutte?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer:

```
        $client->getClient()->get($img_url, ['save_to' => $img_url_save_name,
            'headers'=>['Referer'=>$src]
            ]);
```

Actually I can set header Referer in `Goutte\Client` and but there's no option to give a path to save image. So I finally use Guzzle Client instead.

Comment: Seems the `save_to` request option has been deprecated in favor of `sink` request option http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#sink